# Page doesn't render when get request is issued by jQuery in a rails 3.2 app

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

In a rails 3.2 app I am having trouble getting a page to render when a get request is issued by jQuery.

In a page:

```
<%= select_tag 'bah', options_from_collection_for_select(@groups, :id, :name, ""), :class => "get_to_edit" %>
```

In my js file:

```
$(".get_to_edit").change(function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var url = "/groups/" + id + "/edit"
    $.get(url, id, function(html) {
    });
});
```

In my controller:

```
  def edit
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
  end
```

In my terminal I'm getting:

```
  Rendered groups/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (4.8ms)
```

Yet, nothing is rendered and no error is indicated.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you didn't copy/paste it but inside your $.get success callback you aren't doing anything with what is returned by the request.

You need something to this effect (to at least debug the return in the developer console):

```
$.get(url, id, function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

I would recommend looking into some of the built in javascript helpers Rails provides. It can do a lot of this for you: http://railscasts.com/episodes/205-unobtrusive-javascript?view=asciicast may be of some help.